# Set start_url on Ionic 4 PWA app instead of home page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4, progressive-web-apps

I have developed sample PWA app using Ionic 4 and Angular PWA tool kit. I need to set home as the `login page` when the user clicked the app icon on his home screen on device. If the user has logged in already then he moves to the next page. i.e. after login page. Let's say dashboard. How can I do that?

Doc: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/#start-url

> The start_url tells the browser where your application should start
>   when it is launched, and prevents the app from starting on whatever
>   page the user was on when they added your app to their home screen.

I have tried this. But it always goes to the `home` page. Not to the login page.

*manifest.json*

```
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/login",
```

*routing.ts*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './pages/home/home.module#HomePageModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'quotes',
    loadChildren: './pages/quotes/quotes/quotes.module#QuotesPageModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'details',
    loadChildren: './pages/quotes/details/details.module#DetailsPageModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: './pages/sign-in/login/login.module#LoginPageModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'signup',
    loadChildren: './pages/sign-in/signup/signup.module#SignupPageModule'
  }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just add a `canActivate: [AuthGuard]` to the home route definition. so by default, your app will want to go to the route `/home`, and if the person isn't logged in it will be redirected to `/login`

Alternatively, in your login route definition, add a `canActivate: [ServiceToCheckIfLoggedIn]`, then in `ServiceToCheckIfLoggedIn` run your logic to check if the user is logged in, If yes, redirect where you want.

Comment: But why this is not working when the user clicked the app icon on Home screen? `"start_url": "/login",`

Comment: make your redirectTo `login` that should help